# Vanilla JavaScript storaged locally the wrong attribution from a selected option to switch the theme when you refresh the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to switch one of 4 theme files with one of two different folders and locally and permanently storage both folder and theme names.

Everything worked until I refreshed the site, `localStorage` stored the wrong folder name and the wrong theme name, for example, if you choose “ion” from “voxel”, then when you refresh, you'll see “cyberpunk” selected, while the console showed “`gusbemacbe/ion.css`”

Here how tree is like:

```
assets/css/tokens
├── gusbemacbe
│   └── cyberpunk.css
└── voxel
    ├── ion.css
    ├── itau.css
    └── iti.css
```

And in the HTML code with explanations:

```html
<!-- the "active_stylesheet" identifier will be caught to change the stylesheet address. Observe "voxel" (folder) and "ion" (theme) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="assets/css/tokens/voxel/ion.css" id="active_stylesheet">

<!-- 
- the "ThemeSelect" identified will be caught to get the option value for the theme name.
- the 'onchange="setFolder()"' command will be caught to get "data-id" value for the folder name.
-->
<select id="ThemeSelect" onchange="setFolder()">
    <option data-id="gusbemacbe" value="cyberpunk" selected>cyberpunk</option>
    <option data-id="voxel"      value="ion">íon</option>
    <option data-id="voxel"      value="itau">itaú</option>
    <option data-id="voxel"      value="iti">iti</option>
</select>

<script src="assets/js/global.js"></script>
```

And in the JavaScript code with explanations:

```js
// this function will change the stylesheet address with the folder and theme values
function changeCSS(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}

// this function will catch the function command at that select element to get the data-id value. 
function setFolder() {
    const e = document.getElementById("ThemeSelect");
    const folder = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id");

    return folder;
}

// this function will create the new address, catching the folder and theme values, and setting to store the values
function setTheme(theme) {

    changeCSS("assets/css/tokens/" + setFolder() + "/" + theme + ".css")

    localStorage.setItem('folder', setfolder());
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}

// this event will catch the option value with the identifider
ThemeSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
    setTheme(this.value)
});

// this will store permanently the storages setted by the functions
const getTheme = () => {
    const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    theme && setTheme(theme);

    const folder = localStorage.getItem('folder');
    folder && setFolder(folder);
}

getTheme();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `dataset` use to get and set `data-...` value.
- `fun(this)` send element.
- `element.value` return select item value.
- `element.dataset.id` return selected item `data-id` value.

`HTML`

```
<select id="ThemeSelect" onchange="setFolder(this)">
```

`JavaScript`

```
function setFolder(element) {
    const folder = element.options[element.selectedIndex].dataset.id + "/" + element.value; // edited
    return folder;
}
```

*I think this code help you! thank you!*

Comment: In JavaScript, it gave a result as undefined.

Comment: you change HTML code

Comment: you need to add argument in function this

Comment: I have already done it before. You have to test `console.log(folder)` to see the result on the browser console. You'll understand.

Comment: Ah, you forgot of `[element.selectedIndex]`, but I am unable to store it. I'll update the detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245683/discussion-between-uttam-nath-and-gustavo-reis).